# How can I estimate the maximum players supported by my multiplayer game?

Tags: sockets, multiplayer, steam, bandwidth, steamworks-api

I'm using [Steam Networking Sockets](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/api/ISteamNetworkingSockets) (via [Facepunch Steamworks](https://wiki.facepunch.com/steamworks/)) to create a multiplayer game. Each player sends messages that are approx. 10 bytes long multiple times per second (currently about 20 times/sec but I could reduce this to more like 5 times/sec when more players join without affecting the experience too much).

What I'm wondering is where to cap the maximum player number. I don't have much previous experience in multiplayer networking. The game is written in a way that it could in theory support "infinite" players in one server, and I'd like to support as many as possible without a low arbitrary cap, but I understand that at some point the bandwidth etc. would be too much and the game would become unplayable.

Is there a decent way to estimate the number of players which would become too much?

Comment: Suppose you have 100 players. Then a player will send 200 bytes per second (20 * 10) and receive 20000 (100 * 200) bytes per second. For such small updates packet overhead is significant, so double the estimates to 400 Bps out and 40000 Bps in. From a network bandwidth perspective, that's not very taxing. Increasing the # of players by a factor of 10 still uses less bandwidth than 1080p streaming video. However, processing all those updates is another story.  That computational burden is game specific, but it will probably be the bottleneck even at 100 users. Experiment to find out.

Comment: Those numbers are just for the players. If you have a central server proxying all the transmissions then for N players it must receive 200 * N Bps and send 200 * N * N Bps (all N players send 200 Bps, and every one of these must be sent to all N players). In that case the network bandwidth at the server is quadratic in the # of players and can be a significant factor.